# Using postMessage from child iframe to parent in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to send data back from an iframe running within my `AngularJS` application. In order to do this I am using the `postMessage()` function.

Within my `AngularJS` controller I have the following:

```
$($window).on("message", function (e) {
  var message = JSON.parse(e.originalEvent.data);
  console.log("my message: " + message);
});
```

Within the `iFrame` I have this:

```
window.parent.postMessage("This is coming from response.php","http://site123.com/test/proto");
```

However when I inspect within the console I see this error:

```
VM4132:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T
```

When I view it in more detail I see that the offending line is this:

```
This is coming from response.php
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: A simple string is not JSON, is it?